# How to display post content in the block editor

Tags: javascript, block-editor, html

I'm building a block that shows a bunch of posts of a custom post type. This is the loop that prints them:

```
{ customposts.map( ( custompost, index ) => {
    return <div key={ index } className="custom-post">
        <h2 id={ custompost.id } className="custom-post-title">{ custompost.title.raw }</h2>
            <div className="custom-post-content">{ custompost.content.rendered }</div>
        </div>;
} ) }
```

But, using either `custompost.content.raw` or `custompost.content.rendered` shows uninterpreted HTML code. In the first case, it prints the blocks markup (with HTML comments), and in the second case, the HTML markup, but in both cases, the code is shown verbatim.

If I wrap this with a `RawHTML` component, the content is shown correctly, but according to the docs, this is discouraged as this is prone to cross-site scripting.

```
// This is discouraged
<div className="custom-post-content"><RawHTML>{ custompost.content.rendered }</RawHTML></div>
```

What is the best practice for displaying post content in the block editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that using `RawHTML` (or [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)) is discouraged and indeed prone to [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks like `<img src=x onerror=alert(1)//>` and `<p>abc<iframe//src=jAva&Tab;script:alert(3)>def</p>`.

But if you need to set HTML directly from React, then you'll have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, either directly (e.g. `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ ({ __html: 'foo <b>bar</b>' }) } />`) or via `RawHTML` in Gutenberg (e.g. `<RawHTML>{ 'foo <b>bar</b>' }</RawHTML>`).

However, whether it's React, jQuery or even vanilla JS (direct access on `innerHTML`), the recommended practice has always been to sanitize the HTML, or ensuring it's safe, before passing it to the browser.

So despite WordPress does not (yet) have HTML sanitization functions *in JS*, there are actually libraries such as [`DOMPurify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify) that we can use to ensure the HTML is safe.

And there are other libraries out there that you could choose from, but I thought `DOMPurify` is awesome, so here's an example assuming you've installed the package:

```js
// At the top in your file:
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
// or you can use wp_enqueue_script() to "normally" load the src/purify.js or
// dist/purify.min.js file, and a global window variable named DOMPurify will
// be available on the page.

// Then somewhere in your code, use DOMPurify.sanitize() to sanitize the HTML:
<div className="custom-post-content">
    <RawHTML>{ DOMPurify.sanitize( custompost.content.rendered ) }</RawHTML>
</div>
```

So I hope that helps & Happy coding! :)